math environment revert behaviour to only tag specific line
When writting a long equation like the following, i often see myself having to write \notag{} for most lines, is there a way for doing something similar to have the starred version of an math environment like flalign* where we specify only the lines we want tagged?
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{derivative}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}\label{eq:1.1-y}
  & \notag
  y
  = \frac{c_0}{\varphi(x)}
  + \frac{1  }{\varphi(x)}
  \,\int{\left(\frac{1}{4}\,x^3\right)\,\varphi(x)\,\odif{x}}
  %
  %
  %
  = &\\[3ex]& \notag
  & \text{Using \eqref{eq:1.1-phi_x}} \\& \notag
  = \frac{c_0}{\left(c_1\,e^{x^2/8}\right)}
  + \frac{1  }{\left(c_1\,e^{x^2/8}\right)}
  \,\int{\left(\frac{1}{4}\,x^3\right)\,\left(c_1\,e^{x^2/8}\right)\,\odif{x}}
  = &\\& \notag
  = \frac{c_0}{\left(c_1\,e^{x^2/8}\right)}
  + \frac{1  }{e^{x^2/8}}
  \,\int{\left(\frac{1}{4}\,x^3\right)\,\left(e^{x^2/8}\right)\,\odif{x}}
  = &\\& \notag
  & \text{Using \eqref{eq:1.1-prim}} \\& \notag
  = c_2\,e^{-x^2/8}
  + \frac{1}{e^{x^2/8}}
  \,\left(
    \left(x^2-8\right)\,e^{x^2/8}
  \right)
  = &\\& 
  = c_2\,e^{-x^2/8}
  + x^2-8
  = &\\& \notag{}
  & \text{Using \eqref{eq:1.1-c_2}} \\& \notag
  = 4\,e^{-x^2/8} + x^2 - 8
  % 
  % 
  % 
  &\\[3ex]& \notag
  c_2 = c_0/c_1
  & 
\end{flalign}
% solving y(0) = -4
\begin{flalign}\label{eq:1.1-c_2}
  & \notag
    & \text{Using \eqref{eq:1.1-y}} \\&
    y(0)
    = c_2\,e^{-0^2/8}+ 0^2 - 8
    = c_2 - 8
    = - 4
    \implies c_2 = 4
  &
\end{flalign}
% φ(x)
\begin{flalign} \label{eq:1.1-phi_x}
  & 
    \varphi(x) 
    = \exp{\left(
      \int{\frac{1}{4}\,x\,\odif{x}}
    \right)}
    = \exp{\left(
      \frac{1}{4} \left( \frac{x^2}{2} + c \right)
    \right)}
    = \exp{\left( \frac{c}{4} \right)}
    \,\exp{\left(
      \frac{x^2}{8}
    \right)}
    % \notag
    % = &\\&
    = c_1\,e^{ \frac{x^2}{8} }
    ; &\\& \notag
    c_1 = e^{c/4}
  & 
\end{flalign}
% prim
\begin{flalign}\label{eq:1.1-prim}
  & 
  P\left(
    \left(\frac{1}{4}\,x^3\right)\,\left(e^{x^2/8}\right)
  \right)
  = 
  P\left(
    \left( x^2 \right)
    \,\left(
      e^{x^2/8}
      \,\frac{x}{4}
    \right)
  \right)
  = 
  P\left(
    \left( x^2 \right) % u
    \,\left( e^{x^2/8} \right)' % v'
  \right)
  \notag{}
  = &\\&
  = 
  % u\,v
  x^2\,P\left(
    \left( e^{x^2/8} \right)'
  \right)
  % P(v\,u')
  - P\left(
    P\left(
      \odv{}{x}\left( e^{x^2/8} \right)
    \right)
    \,\odv{x^2}{x}
  \right)
  \notag{}
  = &\\&
  = 
  x^2\,e^{x^2/8} 
  - P\left(
    e^{x^2/8}
    \,2\,x
  \right)
  = 
  x^2\,e^{x^2/8} 
  - 8
  \,P\left(
    e^{x^2/8}
    \,x/4
  \right)
  \notag{}
  = &\\&
  = 
  \left(x^2-8\right)
  \,e^{x^2/8} 
  & 
\end{flalign}
\end{document}



First of all, provide a full compilable MWE with \documentclass{}, preamble with packages you have intension to use plus custom macros, and then a content between \begin{document}...\end{document}. If compilation fails, add description about what it is you would like to achieve. It's all right to add a screenshot of the final form of your equation--does not have to be in LaTeX.

How or where is \odif defined?

\int takes upper and lower limits, but not an argument delimited by curly braces.

Yes Celdor you are right, there you go i added the mwe

\odif is defined in the derivative package Mico, also yes i know \int doesnt have the third argument the brackets are just to help with organisation, indentation and to be easily switched to a () when needed

Eons ago I tinkered the following macro \yesnumber (opposite of \nonumber :-)), though I never really used it so I can't guarantee for its success...
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}% twocolumn for smaller snapshot

\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\yesnumber}{\incr@eqnum\tag{\theequation}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Text
\begin{equation}
a
\end{equation}
text
\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
  &= c\\
  &= d \yesnumber \label{baz}\\
  &= e\\
  &= f\\
  &= g \label{foo} \yesnumber \\ % order is irrelevant
  &= h\\
  &= i
\end{align*}
text
\begin{equation}
X
\end{equation}
See Eqs.~\eqref{baz} and \eqref{foo}.
\end{document}



yup thats exactly what i was looking for, thanks!

Did you consider \newcommand{\yesnumber}{\refstepcounter{equation} \tag{\theequation}}? That would make using \makeatletter and \makeatother unnecessary.

@Mico Erm, as I said, eons ago; I don't really know any more. \incr@eqnum is \refstepcounter{equation}\let\incr@eqnum\@empty, so it is a safety measure against using it twice in a row. But using \yesnumber twice will give an error about multiple \tags anyway, so you might have a point. I have to think about it.

LaTeX does not have a built-in macro to add eq. number in starred environments. The closest you can do is manually increase equation number, add an anchor for a label and display the eq. number via \tag{}. For instance
\refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:this-line}
\tag{\the\value{equation}}

Make sure \label{} is used after \refstepcounter.
I believe the above answers your question.

The example you provided has multiple errors and formatting issues. I believe the missing definition \odiff refers to an integration variable dx. The macros \left( and \right) are not recommended (see these answers). If you need to have them, you could at least load mleftright package and use their improved versions \mleft( and \mright).
Also, if you want to insert text between equations and maintain formatting, use
\intertext{...}

defined in amsmath instead of \text{}. mathtools package also defines a more compact form
\shortintertext{...}

Beware mathtools loads amsmath in background and hence there is no need to load it, explicitly.
Here's your example. I added some dummy text around with a few more equations to demonstrate the numbering is working.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % Dummy text

\ProvideDocumentCommand\odif{m}{\mathop{d#1}}


\begin{document}
\kant[1][1]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:first}
    y = f(x).
\end{equation}

\kant[1][2]
\begin{align*}
    y &= \frac{c_0}{\varphi(x)}
        + \frac{1}{\varphi(x)}
        \int \biggl( \frac{1}{4}x^3 \biggr) \varphi(x) \odif{x}
\intertext{Using \eqref{eq:1.1-phi_x}}
    &= \frac{c_0}{\bigl(c_1 e^{x^2/8}\bigr)}
       + \frac{1}{\bigl(c_1 e^{x^2/8}\bigr)}
       \int \biggl(\frac{1}{4} x^3 \biggr) \Bigl(c_1 e^{x^2/8}\Bigr) \odif{x} \\ 
    &= \frac{c_0}{\left(c_1 e^{x^2/8}\right)}
       + \frac{1}{e^{x^2/8}}
       \int \biggl(\frac{1}{4} x^3 \biggr) \Bigl( e^{x^2/8}\Bigr) \odif{x}
\intertext{Using \eqref{eq:1.1-prim}}
    &= c_2e^{-x^2/8}
       + \frac{1}{e^{x^2/8}} \Bigl(\bigl(x^2-8\bigr) e^{x^2/8}\Bigr) \\
    &= c_2e^{-x^2/8} + x^2 - 8
\intertext{Using \eqref{eq:1.1-c_2}}
    &= 4e^{-x^2/8} + x^2 - 8 \\
    c_2 &= c_0/c_1
    \refstepcounter{equation}\label{eq:line}
    \tag{\the\value{equation}}
\end{align*}

\kant[1][3]
\begin{equation}\label{eq:second}
    y = \sin(x).
\end{equation}

References: equation \eqref{eq:first} ... equation \eqref{eq:line} ... equation \eqref{eq:second}.
\end{document}



I followed your suggestion and created a command to tag the specific line:
\NewDocumentCommand\tagthiseq{m}{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}%
  \IfValueT{\label{#1}}%
  \tag{\the\value{equation}}%
}

but i noticed that the numbering doesnt follow the other equations when i redefine with
\renewcommand\theequation{\arabic{group}.{\arabic{equation}}}
where group is just another counter

nevermind substituting \the\value{equation} for \theequation solved, this worked for me, thanks

Oh also thank you for the recommendation on intertext and the m delimiters, will definitely take a look

I think you made mistake in your macro. It is supposed to be \IfValueT{#1}{\label{#1}} and you seemed to miss checking for the input parameter {#1}. Anyway, I am glad you sorted it out. \theequation is the right way to query equations because it returns the correct form of a counter, not just a counter number. In this case it didn't make a difference.
